# PyTorch out of GPU memory in test loop

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

For the following training program, training and validation are all ok.
Once reach to Test method, I have `CUDA out of memory`. What should I change so that I have enough memory to test as well.

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch.nn.functional as f
class CnnLstm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CnnLstm, self).__init__()
        self.cnn = CNN()
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=180000, hidden_size=256, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)#stacked LSTM with 2 layers
        #print(num_classes)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(256, num_classes)
        #print('after num_classes')

    def forward(self, x):
        #print(x.shape)
        batch_size, time_steps, channels, height, width = x.size()
        c_in = x.view(batch_size * time_steps, channels, height, width)
        _, c_out = self.cnn(c_in)
        r_in = c_out.view(batch_size, time_steps, -1)
        r_out, (_, _) = self.rnn(r_in)
        r_out2 = self.linear(r_out[:, -1, :])
        return f.log_softmax(r_out2, dim=1)


class TrainCNNLSTM:
    def __init__(self):
        self.seed = 1
        self.batch_size = 8
        self.validate_batch_size = 8
        self.test_batch_size = 1
        self.epoch = 20
        self.learning_rate = 0.01
        self.step = 100
        self.train_loader = None
        self.validate_loader = None
        self.test_loader = None
        #print('before')
        self.model = CnnLstm().to(device)
        #print('after')
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def load_data(self):
        data_loader = DataLoader()
        self.train_loader = data_loader.get_train_data(self.batch_size)
        self.validate_loader = data_loader.get_validate_data(self.validate_batch_size)
        self.test_loader = data_loader.get_test_data(self.test_batch_size)

    def train(self):  
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CyclicLR(optimizer, base_lr=self.learning_rate/100.0, max_lr=self.learning_rate, step_size_up=13)
        #optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
        for epoch in range(self.epoch):
            t_losses=[]
            for iteration, (data, target) in enumerate(self.train_loader):
                data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=1)
                data = torch.FloatTensor(data)
                data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
                data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                output = self.model(data)
                loss = self.criterion(output, target)
                #loss = f.nll_loss(output, target)
                t_losses.append(loss)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                scheduler.step() 
                if iteration % self.step == 0:
                   print('Epoch: {} | train loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))
            avgd_trainloss = sum(t_losses)/len(t_losses)
            self.validate(epoch, avgd_trainloss)

    def validate(self, epoch, avg_tloss):
        v_losses=[]
        with torch.no_grad():
            for iteration, (data, target) in enumerate(self.validate_loader):
                data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=1)
                data = torch.FloatTensor(data)
                data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
                data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)              
                output = self.model(data)
                loss = self.criterion(output, target)
                #loss = f.nll_loss(output, target)
                v_losses.append(loss)
        avgd_validloss = sum(v_losses)/len(v_losses)
        print('Epoch: {} | train loss: {:.4f} | validate loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, avg_tloss, avgd_validloss))

    def test(self):
        test_loss = []
        correct = 0
        for data, target in self.test_loader:
            data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=1)
            data = torch.FloatTensor(data)
            data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
            data, target = Variable(data, volatile=True), Variable(target)
            output = self.model(data)
            loss = self.criterion(output, target)
            #f.nll_loss(output, target, size_average=False).item()  # sum up batch loss
            test_loss.append(loss)
            pred = torch.max(output, 1)[1].data.squeeze()
            correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).long().cpu().sum()

        test_loss = sum(test_loss)/len(test_loss)
        print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(test_loss, correct, len(self.test_loader.dataset),
                100. * correct / len(self.test_loader.dataset)))


train = TrainCNNLSTM()
train.load_data()
train.train()
train.test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `.item()` on your `loss` when appending it to the list of losses:

```
loss = self.criterion(output, target)
test_loss.append(loss.item())
```

This avoids accumulating tensors in a list which are still attached to the computational graph. I would say the same for your accuracy.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The reason is I need `with torch.no_grad():` before  `for data, target in self.test_loader:` like in validate method.

Comment: Your point is also a good point so that it won't waste some storage.